# Why couldn't the Fellowship use the Eagles?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

For those unfamiliar with the video (and unable to access it), Gandalf basically summons some eagles, they fly over Mt Doom and drop the ring in.

I guess my question is not so much "why they didn't" which implies the characters had an option to, but is there anything in the LOTR canon that prevents this from being an option?  I've read the books (once, ages ago, I'm more familiar with the movies) but can't recall any logic or reason in the stories that would prevent such an approach to disposing of the ring.

It goes without saying that the stories (books and films) are great, but having eagle's available does beg the question.

Comment: Cheers - my powers of search are obviously very poor

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Enjoy all the answers!